# ssh2_auth_pubkey_file not possible to connect with working public/private key

Tags: php, ssh

After upgrading to `Debian 12 Bookworm` and `PHP 8.2` it's no longer possible to connect via SSH2 with PHP

I'm using two WORKING privat/public keys...

The PHP script is a cronjob running as `root`

When connecting via command line everything works fine....!?

```
ssh remote-server.com
```

But when connecting with PHP this error is returned

Error

```
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for root using public key: Username/PublicKey combination invalid .../SSH.php(29)
```

Code

```
$user           = 'root';
$host           = 'remote-server.com';
$private_key    = '/root/id_rsa';
$public_key     = '/root/id_rsa.pub';

if(!is_readable($private_key) || !is_readable($public_key)){
    echo "RSA keys not found\n";
}

echo 'private key: '.file_get_contents($private_key)."\n";
echo 'public key: '.file_get_contents($public_key)."\n";
echo "host: $host\n";
echo "user: $user\n";

if(!$session = ssh2_connect($host)){
    echo "Could not connect to '$host'\n";
}

if(!ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($session, $user, $public_key, $private_key)){
    echo "Could not authenticate to '$host'\n";
}
```

What am I missing?

Key generation

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

The RSA keys are **without** passphrase

## update

Have now tried to generate the keys like this (still with **empty** passphrase)

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa
```

The code outputs

```
private key: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

public key: ssh-rsa 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 root@xxx

host: remote-server.com
user: root
PHP Warning:  ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for root using public key: Username/PublicKey combination invalid in /root/test_ssh.php on line 21

Warning: ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for root using public key: Username/PublicKey combination invalid in /root/test_ssh.php on line 21
Could not authenticate to 'remote-server.com'
```

Comment: What user are you running that `ssh remote-server.com` as?

Comment: Have you checked if PHP SSH2 Extension is installed? run php -m | grep ssh2

Comment: Check permissions on the key files. If this were a RHEL server I'd also suggest checking SELinux logs for failures, not sure if AppArmor provides the same protections?

Comment: Also might be worth mentioning what version of PHP you're upgrading *from*.

Comment: @JimRedmond everything is running as `root`. Both the cronjob that runs the php script and also when I try `ssh domain.com` from command line

Comment: @DavaGordon yes it is `# php -m | grep ssh2
ssh2` I can connect but can't verify the keys

Comment: @miken32 where can I find thse logs?

Comment: @miken32 upgraded from `PHP 8.1`

Comment: Is this a CLI script? If not, "everything is running as root" --- I doubt your PHP code is. Your keys need to be created/chown'd as the web server user.

Comment: @PaulAllsopp the script is running as `root` as a cronjob

Comment: Did you try executing the script directly (not through cron)?

Comment: @Olivier same outcome

Comment: @clarkk tested with PHP 8.2.15 and PHP 8.1.27 with SSH2 Module php-ssh2 amd64 1.4-1 , I confirm I'm able to reproduce your issue both on a Debian 12 system (2 of them, just to be sure), on Alma Linux 8.9 and on Ubuntu 20.04. Same result: the SSH log shows "Received disconnect from XX.XX.XX.XXport XXXXX:11: PECL/ssh2 (http://pecl.php.net/packages/ssh2) [preauth]" and "Disconnected from authenticating user root XX.XX.XX.XX port XXXXX [preauth]". I guess it's an issue related to the SSH2 module itself.

Comment: Please do not *****EVER***** use the key you just announced to the Internet.

Comment: @JimRedmond I don't use these keys in production.. Thats why I posted them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the server, more logs from the server could help (sshd is going to tell why it refuses to authenticate the client).
The issue is likely related to RSA with SHA1 being deprecated. I saw the same issue but didn't find a way to work around it using libssh2 1.10 which is shipped with Debian 12.

Without more details, I think your best shot is to generate a key of another type (not `rsa`, e.g. `ecdsa` or `ed25519`), add the public part of the new key to the `authorized_keys` on the server, and use it instead; it will likely just work (or at least it did for me).

Comment: Where can I find the ssh logs on the server?

Comment: `ecdsa` keys works :)

Comment: Either in journald (you'll need to use `journalctl`), or `/var/log/syslog`, or `/var/log/auth.log`. However, I suspect that the issue here is in the libssh2: [the changelog](https://libssh2.org/changes.html) says that 1.11 added RSA-SHA2. I'm not too much into the subject, though; I just wasn't able to make it work with libssh2 :(

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that you are generating the public/private keys in a wrong format.

try: `ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa`

I guess the file permissions of your generated key files are not an issue because you are running as root.

Comment: Have tried to generate the keys as you proposed, but get the same error.. Have updated my question